# Password hash being generated differently every time

Tags: java, hash, jetty

I'm working on password protecting a jetty server I'm building. I'm using Java's MessageDigest class to hash the passwords. I created this test class and it's working fine:

```
    String hash = "<hashOfMyPassword";
    String pass = "<myPassword>";
    byte[] data = pass.getBytes();
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    md.update(data);
    MessageDigest passMD = null;
    try {
        passMD = (MessageDigest) md.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] passHash = passMD.digest();
    System.out.println(passHash.toString().equals(hash));
```

but when I move it to my jetty server it starts acting oddly. Here's that method:

```
public void handle(String s, Request req, HttpServletRequest hreq,
            HttpServletResponse hres) throws IOException, ServletException {
        hres.setContentType("text/plain");
        hres.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        req.setHandled(true);
        if (!running) {

            //Validate password
            String pass = hreq.getParameter("password");
            hres.getWriter().println(pass);
            byte[] data = pass.getBytes();
            MessageDigest md = null;
            try {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            md.update(data);
            MessageDigest passMD = null;
            try {
                passMD = (MessageDigest) md.clone();
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] passHash = passMD.digest();
            hres.getWriter().println(passHash.toString());
            if (passHash.toString().equals(hash)) {
               //dostuff
            } else {
                hres.getWriter().println("invalid password");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

(before anyone says something, I know I'm passing the password weirdly, but that's okay for this project)

This is the exact same this as before but this time I'm always getting different hashes, and the passwords never match. I pass the same password in twice and the first time I get something like "[B@33ab7e65" and the next I get "[B@58eb5b4".

I'm using curl to access the server btw.

Any ideas about what's happening? This is really weird.

Comment: At the top of the class. it's private static String hash. I generated it before hand.

Comment: Protection of passwords via simple hashing is **ineffective**, I recommend you switch to an algorithm like `PBKDF #2`, `Bcrypt` or `Scrypt`. Java itself contains support for `PBKDF #2` and the others can be obtained via well established public libraries (e.g. Bouncy Castle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're converting `passHash`, a byte array, to a string with `toString`. This is not actually getting at the contents of your array at all—Java's implementation of `toString` on arrays is rather unhelpful, and it simply prints out a part of the address of the array's location in memory.

Don't compare the hash using string equality, compare it directly! Type `hash` as a byte array as well, and use `Arrays.equals()` to compare them.

```
Arrays.equals(passHash, hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are calling toString() on the hash and not using the hash at all. You cannot convert a byte array into a string by calling toString().

```
 passHash.toString().equals(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Commons Lang 3's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) includes a reliable way to generate the string version of an array.

```
   @Test
   public void arrayToString(){
      int[] a = {1,2,3};
      int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, 3);
      String aRawToString = a.toString();
      String bRawToString = b.toString();
      String aCommonsLangToString = ArrayUtils.toString(a);
      String bCommonsLangToString = ArrayUtils.toString(b);
      Assert.assertNotEquals(aRawToString, bRawToString);
      Assert.assertEquals(aCommonsLangToString, bCommonsLangToString);
      System.out.println(aRawToString);
      System.out.println(bRawToString);
      System.out.println(aCommonsLangToString);
      System.out.println(bCommonsLangToString);
   }
```

The output below demonstrates the problem with using toString (which generates different answers for identical arrays) and the solution.

```
[I@504814f9
[I@2c59109c
{1,2,3}
{1,2,3}
```

This line of code from the original question:

```
hres.getWriter().println(passHash.toString());
```

can be rewritten as

```
hres.getWriter().println(ArrayUtils.toString(passHash));
```

to generate consistent diagnostic output.